# State space model out of sample forecasting with statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels, state-space

I'm using a sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel to fit a State Space model in Python with the library statsmodels. I have a time series and I'm interested in the State (not the dependent variable itself). First of all, I splitted the data into training and testing sets.

I fitted the model as usual on my training set and get my parameters estimates. From the result, which is a
`statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEResults`, I want to use my out of sample data and the estimates from the in sample model, to predict the out of sample states...

However, using some functions such as `res_spx.predicted_state`, I am only able to get the in sample estimated states. How can I use all my data (train and test) but only fit the model on training data and get all (in and out of sample) states estimates ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The estimates of the states depend not only on the parameters, but also on the dataset used by the model to create the state estimates.

Let's assume that there are 100 observations in your training dataset (`t=0, 1, ..., 99`) and 10 observations in your test dataset (`t=100, 101, ..., 109`). We'll also assume that you only estimate the parameters once, using the 100 training observations.

Then, here are a couple of options for state estimates:

```
# Split the data
train, test = ...

# Construct your state space model using only
# the training dataset...
mod = SSM(train, ...)

# ... so that the parameters will be estimated
# using only the training dataset, t=0, 1, ..., 99
res = mod.fit()

# Estimates of the states for t=100, ..., 109
# using only training data, t=0, 1, ..., 99
print(res.get_forecast(10).prediction_results.predicted_state.T)

# Estimates of the t=100, ..., 109 states
# using entire dataset, t=0, 1, ..., 109
res_append = res.extend(test)
print(res_append.smoothed_state.T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when using the method `extend`, I get the following error from the base code: `NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented in the base class and must be set up by each specific model.` It is similar if I try to use the `apply` or the `append` methods... do you know how to overpass this problem?